# VBA to loop through cells with date in worksheet 1, extract to worksheet 2 if month&year match

Tags: vba, date, loops

I tried it with VLookup and Index&Match, but it looks like only a VBA Loop can help me:

I have a list starting with a date in the first worksheet.
Now I want to loop through this list, checking if the month&year of the date in the first column of the list, match month&year in the second worksheet.
If so, the information in the rest of the row of the matching date should be copied to Worksheet 2.

I uploaded the worksheet with some sample data here: https://cignifi.box.com/s/a6k03lh0bfe9ob53d4jy

Every help would be highly appreciated! I have some understanding of VBA but not good enough for this type of question...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your finished product is supposed to be but this subroutine will do as you have requested. It will overwrite any information that is already on Sheet2 with the information from the table on Sheet1. Let me know if this doesn't do what you were looking for.
You can adjust which columns data is transferred to and from by changing the variables at the beginning.

EDIT: Added code to check the Account Name column for the next blank and use that row number to copy to:

```
Sub ProcessTableData()
    Dim wsSource, wsDestination As Worksheet
    Dim rowSourceStart, colSourceDate, rSource, colDestStart As Long
    Dim rowDestMonthYear, cDest, rowDestInsertAt As Long
    Dim destBlankColumnCount As Integer
    Dim colDestRegion, colDestAccountName, colDestPotentialName As Integer
    Dim colDestAmount, colDestWeightedAmount As Integer
    Dim colSourceRegion, colSourceAccountName, colSourcePotentialName As Integer
    Dim colSourceAmount, colSourceWeightedAmount As Integer

    Set wsSource = Sheet1
    Set wsDestination = Sheet2

    'Destination column offsets from month column
    colDestRegion = 0
    colDestAccountName = 1
    colDestPotentialName = 2
    colDestAmount = 3
    colDestWeightedAmount = 4

    'Source columns
    colSourceRegion = 5
    colSourceAccountName = 3
    colSourcePotentialName = 4
    colSourceAmount = 6
    colSourceWeightedAmount = 7

    colSourceDate = 2 'Source column for date
    rowSourceStart = 3 'Source starting row

    rowDestMonthYear = 2 'Destination row to check for month & year matching

    rSource = rowSourceStart
    'loop until the date field on the source sheet is blank
    Do While wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceDate).Value <> ""
        cDest = 1
        destBlankColumnCount = 0
        'loop through the destination columns until we've seen 5 blanks
        '(only 3 are ever expected)
        Do Until destBlankColumnCount > 5
            If wsDestination.Cells(rowDestMonthYear, cDest).Value <> "" Then
                destBlankColumnCount = 0
                'check if month matches
                If Month(wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceDate).Value) = wsDestination.Cells(rowDestMonthYear, cDest).Value Then
                    'check if year matches
                    If Year(wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceDate).Value) = wsDestination.Cells(rowDestMonthYear, (cDest + 1)).Value Then
                        'find last row to copy data to by finding the next blank "Account Name" row
                        rowDestInsertAt = (rowDestMonthYear + 2)
                        Do Until wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestAccountName)).Value = ""
                            rowDestInsertAt = rowDestInsertAt + 1
                        Loop
                        'copy field data
                        wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestAccountName)).Value = wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceAccountName).Value
                        wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestPotentialName)).Value = wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourcePotentialName).Value
                        wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestRegion)).Value = wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceRegion).Value
                        wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestAmount)).Value = wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceAmount).Value
                        wsDestination.Cells(rowDestInsertAt, (cDest + colDestWeightedAmount)).Value = wsSource.Cells(rSource, colSourceWeightedAmount).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                destBlankColumnCount = destBlankColumnCount + 1
            End If
            cDest = cDest + 1
        Loop
        rSource = rSource + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ross!
Wow - that works fantastic and does what I was looking for!

Now the are two things left:
I have multiple entries for the same month but currently it only displays the first entry of each month - how do we check for multiples? (Sorry, I know this was not obvious from the sample I uploaded - my bad...)

Can we maybe get the code to jump to a new sheet if the date becomes 2014? And so forth...

Many thanks for your great help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help. However, I believe this web site is about supporting individuals who want a helping hand as they teach themselves how to program. I suggest researching and trying to accomplish a process on your own first and then coming here when you have not been able to make the process work on your own. [faq#questions] By writing the entire subroutine and handing it to you I have really not helped you to progress in learning unless you study the code and understand what each line does. If the coding above does work as requested please accept it as an answer. -Thanks

Comment: Hi Ross,
many thanks for the update-the multiple entries now work!
I know that this site mostly serves the need to help programmers...but I always learn the most from seeing how other people solve problems - and for this problem I couldn't find a already existing solution or alike. And I lacked the understanding of how to structure the coding - your approach clearly showed it to me, so I learned how to program =)

Unfortunately I encounter a problem I don't see why its occuring as the code does not change anything related to it: all the values of the weighted amount lack three zeros in sheet2

Comment: Perhaps it is the formatting, the value is being transferred directly from one cell to another. If it is not the formatting can you give some example values of what a number was on Sheet1 and what it became on Sheet2?

Comment: @user2149841 Great- please click the checkmark below the Answer subtitle to accept this section as the answer. Thanks!